# How to specify UTC timezone for spring-boot-starter-data-jpa + PostgreSQL timestamp

Tags: postgresql, spring-data-jpa

Table column is creating with:

```
@Column(columnDefinition = "TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE")
private OffsetDateTime timeStamp;
```

When Instant epoch value (ex:2020-05-25T16:16:16Z) is saved it is appending the local time hours in DB (ex: 2020-05-26 04:16:16+12).

Please suggest how can we enforce the same UTC value to be stored in DB.

Comment: do you want to enforce UTC timezone for all entities ?

Comment: `timestamp WITH time zone` **does** store the value normalized to UTC

Comment: How do you store an `Instant` value in an `OffsetDateTime` value? And if you have an `OffsetDateTime` value in the entity why are you surprised it has a an _offset_?

Comment: Yes. enforcing all the entities also fine. I verified some of the stackoverflow incidents but they are most of them on MySQL way of setting in application.config file but that is not working for Postgresql.